# Кодировка русских символов

Tags: c++, c++builder

Копируя русские символы из Edit и вставляя их в браузер получается кракозябра. Как исправить?

```
std::string s_russian =
            {
                    "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцшщъыьэюя"
            };
```

Comment: Переключаю раскладку на русский - всё копирует нормально

Comment: Как связаны между собой упомянутые `Edit` и код? Какая винда, какой браузер? Версия билдера и т.п.?

Comment: @alexolut win 10, bulider 6, chrome

Comment: В Builder6 нет поддержки Unicode в родных компонентах. Может помочь `TNT Unicode Controls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил в mouseOver переключение на русскую раскладку и всё нормально копируется

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону std::wstring и UnicodeString для элементов builder